# Android Toast throwing error

Tags: java, android, toast

My main activity "My_Gallery" is calling a function from another class "DataCall". In DataCall I am trying to Toast a variable to make sure I have the correct info in there.

```
Toast.makeText(DataCall.this, url_param_string, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

But I am getting the following error under `DataCall.this`

```
Cannot use this in a static context
```

Not sure what I am missing. Thanks in advance for any feedback.

*Also I am new to Eclipse and I see in debug mode there is a window for variables but it is empty.*

Comment: pass the context from the activity of My_Gallery and use that instead of DataCall.this

Comment: Another way to tracking value while debugging is use Log to output value, example: Log.i(DEBUG, YourTrackingVariable);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's exactly the error. You can't call `this` on a static context, like a static function.

If you need a context for Toast. Try the application context:  `Context.getApplicationContext()`

Answer (score 0):

Dentro del metodo agrega un parametro adicional que indique el contexto:
ejemplo:

```
public static void sendMessage(String message, Context contexto) 
{
    if (mRfcommClient.getState() != Bluetooth_lib.STATE_CONNECTED) 
    {   
      Toast.makeText(contexto, "No conectado", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 
    } 
}
```